# How to write python unittest for function that returns huge sparse matrix

Tags: python, unit-testing

So, I have a function that constructs a huge sparse matrix. The structure of the function is this:

```
def return_matrix():

    for i in range(i_res):
        for j in range(j_res):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                # code that adds value to sparse matrix
            elif (i == 1 and j==1) or (i==i_res-1 and j==j_res-1):
                # code that adds value to sparse matrix
            #and so on
```

So this function is basically long chain of elif statements.

What is a correct way of writing unittest in such cases?

Comment: Each `elif` can call a different function to do its processing (what is after the #s in your current code), and then your unit-tests would work on that function and test its behaviour: with valid values, invalid values, min/max values, etc.

Comment: And yet I can make mistakes in ordering those one-line functions inside my elifs. I.e. while each of my tiny functions would pass tests, my main return_matrix function would produce wrong result.

Comment: You can change the `elif`s to `if`s, which will make them independent of one another, and thus will reduce your chances of making mistakes due to wrong ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Try to test *what* your code is doing instead of *how* it's doing it. Your test probably doesn't need to worry about the individual if statements and their order in the code. Instead, think about what features of the matrix are necessary for it to be correct.

I don't know anything about your requirements, so I'll just make up some things that might be good for testing:

- values in each row are monotonically increasing from left to right
- odd columns have odd values
- no duplicate values within a row

I can imagine writing a test case for each of these that would iterate through the items in the matrix and check.

Obviously, you have to think about your own requirements to see what are the qualities of the result that you can examine in an automated test. How would you know if the result were wrong?

Comment: Well, the obvious way to check if my matrix is right is to use it for the problem for which I know the answer and to see if my matrix leads to the same answer. That is the way  I always did it in the past. But it seems to me that it has nothing to do with Unit testing the right way.

Comment: Are there one or two other simple examples that you can use to test the same matrix? Are there smaller matrices that could be generated by the same code and compared more easily? You might find this chapter on the [philosophy of test automation](http://xunitpatterns.com/Philosophy%20Of%20Test%20Automation.html) helpful. The whole book is really good.